# Problems with Stack Overflow when using Linux Google Chrome?

Tags: support, status-norepro, google-chrome, browser-cache

Is anybody else having problems with https://stackoverflow.com/ when browsing the site through Linux Google Chrome?

It appears that some (most?) JavaScript driven buttons do not work.

Examples:

- Incorrectly reports that the email address is invalid
- Upvote button has no effect
- Favorite button has no effect.

Comment: Like... what? Can you bring more details to the table?

Comment: Like trying to upvote a question: pressing the button has no effect.

Comment: Have cleared your cache?

Comment: I am puzzled now... clearing the cache solved the problem... care to explain?

Comment: Jean-Lou: Don't celebrate too soon... I wouldn't be surprised to hear that it's only a temporary effect. If not though, I'll certainly be clearing my cache tomorrow :)

Comment: If it's the same problem as I've been seeing, other symptoms include a lack of answer preview and a lack of editing toolbar, with shortcut keys failing too.

Comment: Linux Chrome or Chromium? I'm not sure how big the difference is, but there are some.

Comment: Indeed, I have the same problem with a completely new Google Chrome (so it cannot be a cache issue) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35075/cannot-vote-with-google-chrome

Comment: Try to disable: "Enable Experimental JavaScript" by going to chrome://flags/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every now and then the team will release some changes and fixes to the code. That includes tweaking of the JavaScript.

If you find the site not responding to your will, say when you vote or any other interaction with the site that involves JavaScript, it's a good idea to clear your cache to see if that solves the problem.

Your machine would have been running a cached version of the JavaScript that might not be as fresh as the new site release would work with. Or referencing something else.

Comment: So you guys (i.e. SO) aren't using ETAG then?

Comment: note that all changes have a revision number appended to the javascript, like so: `file.js?v=1234` so if true, some caching proxy is ignoring querystrings.

Answer (score 3):

I've had problems today and yesterday, yes. (I believe there was a new drop over the weekend... or it may just have been that that's when our desktop updater picked it up.) I don't know whether the version I use is exactly the same as the version you're using (I don't know whether internally we're ahead of the public "dev" channel or behind it; I *suspect* we're on it) but it sounds like the same problem.

I've found that restarting Chrome solves the issue *temporarily*, but that it becomes problematic again fairly soon. I've switched to Firefox for SO (and related sites) temporarily; hopefully it'll be fixed in the next version. (If it isn't, I'll try to delve a bit deeper and work out what's going wrong.)

Until now, it's been working very well - I'm looking forward to normal service resuming :)

Comment: Wouldn't the issue be dampened through the use of ETAG HTTP header?

Comment: Without knowing what the issue really is, I couldn't say.

Comment: @jon: Of course. I am assuming they have a 'refresh problem' (as hinted by @random) in which case they might be using the "expires" HTTP header instead of ETAG.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that's the problem... but we'll see.