# Cannot vote with Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, google-chrome

I have no idea if it is a Stack Overflow problem or a Google Chrome one. Anyway, with Firefox, I can vote Up or Down, with Google Chrome (Debian 32-bits version, downloaded one hour ago), clicking on the arrows makes nothing, no change at all.

I note also that I cannot see the Your Answer edition area at the bottom.

It may be the same problem as [Problems with Stack Overflow when using Linux Google Chrome?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23030/problems-with-stack-overflow-when-using-linux-google-chrome).

If, following Jon Skeet's suggestion, I flush the cache, it changes nothing. If I logout from SO, I can see the Your Answer edition area at the bottom. It disappears when I'm logged in.

Comment: Checking the obvious - are you sure you're logged in?

Comment: Yes, I can edit answers, I can add comments, etc.

Comment: Fair enough - I've been bitten with that sort of thing myself before, something doesn't work and you make assumptions.

Comment: I've used almost all dev builds created in the last 6 months and have never had such a problem. However, Chrome does seem to have a tendency to randomly break stuff at times.

Comment: Indeed, I tried on a machine where the version of Chrome was downloaded a few weeks ago and this one works.

Answer (score 5):

Try flushing the browser's cache - that's what I've seen giving me problems very occasionally on Chrome.

Out of interest, do you see the various icons (bold, italic etc) and the answer preview when you view a question?

Voting in general certainly works with Chrome - and unless today's update has broken it, it works with Chrome on Linux too.

Comment: Flushing the cache? You mean reloading the page? If yes, it changed nothing. If no, I did not find the option "Flush the cache".

Comment: Indeed, I do NOT see "the various icons (bold, italic etc) and the answer preview when I view a question".

Comment: No, the cache; spanner icon -> options -> personal stuff -> browsing data -> clear browsing data. Select "empty the cache" / period=everything, and click "clear browsing data". Done.

Comment: Thanks, Marc, I can flush the cache now.

Comment: But flushing the cache changed nothing (although logging out made the answer preview reappear).

Comment: Thanks, Jon - I had the same problem as the OP and clearing the cache solved the problem for me.

Comment: For the record: I had this problem in Firefox (8.0) and reloading the page with cache override (ctrl-F5) helped.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running the adblock extension.  If that is so, you may have blocked one or more ads, and blocked the voting arrows as a side effect.

You can fix this by going into adblock options, and finding the "block an ad that the filter missed"   Odds are there is a tag of some sort there associated with stackoverflow.com
or perhaps just one named IMG.   Unblocking these, may bring the missing arrows back.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem.  Pausing AdBlock had no effect. I fixed it by clearing the cache:

- Preferences
- Under the hood
- Clear Browsing Data
- Empty the Cache

Chrome took about 30 secs to clear, but on completion when I reloaded the page I could see the Orange 'flag-up' marker that wasn't clearly visible (I'd previously switched for FireFox to flag-up) - and I was then able to flag-up the question.

Comment: This is likely an entirely different problem. It might be a good idea to post this as a new question instead of an answer on a 4 month old norepro'd bug report

Comment: @yi it is probably related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89224/does-anyone-have-problems-viewing-so-in-chrome-11/90259#90259