# Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load. (ChromeOS - Cr-48)

Tags: support, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message)

I am using Google ChromeOS on my Cr-48, and I'm getting this error, in a red bar on top of the screen. It seems that ALL JavaScript is not working, because I don't even get to see the preview as I write this post. I do have JavaScript enable, and it works on other domains just fine, the only problem I'm having is here, with any of the Stack Overflow domains, or stack exchange domains.

**Chrome OS**: 0.12.433.57 (Official Build) beta-channel x86-mario
**Google Chrome**: 12.0.742.68
**WebKit**: 534.30 (branches/chromium/742@87129)
**V8**: 3.2.10.13
**User Agent**: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 0.12.433) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.68 Safari/534.30

Also, I can't comment because that requires JavaScript to work on the domain. And I do know that JavaScript works on other domains, because for example, I can run code from http://html5demos.com/ without a problem, and it works just fine.

Comment: There are at least four related questions listed down the right-hand side ([here's one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message)). I suggest doing a search for your error message next time.

Comment: @CanSpice, turns out it was an error with that version of ChromeOS that was fixed. So in fact any question that was on the right-hand side was NOT related to my problem.

Comment: i also encountered this matter just today... sigh!
I just remember yesterday before i turned off my pc, I did some changes using Internet Booster program.... I think that what made it problem. TO enhance the speed, tough. :D