# Load jQuery from Stack's CDN if Google's CDN is blocked (or always)

Tags: feature-request, javascript, cdn, jquery

Google's CDN is nice, but it's not 100% reliable for all users. It occasionally fails to load for me. Other users [have had trouble with it due to sloppily-configured networks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/employer-blocks-jquery-from-google-doh), and some [may prefer to block external scripts by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133784/stackexchange-heavy-reliance-on-external-scripts).

It's one more possible point of failure. It would be preferable if Stack Exchange didn't *depend* on it.

If you don't want to stop using it, consider adding a fallback if it fails to load. Something like this:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write('<script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/content/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No reason not to have safety nets and backups in place.  I like the idea.

Comment: +1 Good idea.  Some more nice methods for doing this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6125487/242

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly

Answer (score 11):

I dislike this proposal cause it cascades.

What about `cdn.sstatic.net`? Should we add a fallback to `sstatic.net`? Perhaps the network is totally disallowing remote resources, what about a second level fallback to `stackoverflow.com`?

What happens if downloading stuff from Google is taking 30 seconds to time out? Now the fallback is going to be mega delayed.

Personally, I see no advantage in using the Google CDN, our CDN outperforms it usually. With the advantage that the connection can be reused later on in the request. Less CDNs = Less randomness.

Additionally I feel a better investment of our resources would be pushing jQuery to load `async`, so you can still see the content even if jQuery is not loaded. (Question/Show page does this partially.)

Now, some may say that Google CDN version of jQuery is incredibly likely to already be on a machine, the reality is that 20% of our page views have an unprimed cache, empty cache is incredibly likely. People are often clicking "refresh" as well forcing a `If-Modified-Since` to Google as well.

Comment: Sure, using `cdn.sstatic.net` instead of Google's CDN also sounds good to me. It doesn't matter if we can load jQuery when we can't load the scripts that use it. +1

Comment: As an aside: showing a warning when `sstatic.net` fails to load might also be easily achieved? That's [already nicely done for jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81546/stackoverflow-com-javascript-disabled-banner/81561#81561), but that very check is in code loaded from `sstatic.net`. So, a warning for `sstatic.net` needs code from the regular domains themselves.

Comment: Just curious: *"the reality is that 20% of our page views have an unprimed cache"* — were you actually somehow measuring the availability of jQuery for those requests?

Comment: @waffles, I disagree with your first paragraph. The proposal does not need to cascade because there's nothing stopping it from being treated as a case-by-case basis. The question would be whether there's a real **observed** problem with a majority of visitors. And as for Google's CDN, there's actually such a real problem. Also see [Use of ajax.googleapis.com not China friendly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258288/632951).

Comment: @Pacerier waffles has left the building best as nickcraver or flag it or something

Comment: @waffles, Btw what's the reason for your retirement?

Comment: @Pacerier too much maple syrup.

Comment: @waffles, Ok.. I'd not quite have the context here..

Comment: @Pacerier I wrote a blog post about why I left years ago, not really on topic here.

Comment: @waffles Well, it is six years later and none of the potential downsides/fears by having a fallback in place you wrote about have (permanently) materialized. I simply can't understand the logic to sit around and do nothing while the site is horribly broken from China.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a good idea.
As a Chinese visitor I'd like to use jQuery CDN from baidu.The URL is https://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Hey, this brings me to an idea. Why not do that with Greasemonkey and let it do some interceptions? In clear print, intercept SE's request to Google CDN and use the Baidu one instead when we're surfin' in from `*.cn`. Can't be rocket science to implement. I would even do it myself; but *simulating* a client from China is simply not the same as connecting *on location*. Because what I've seen so far in statements from the staff means to me that rather hell freezes over than they'd ever agree on implementing a fallback for Chinese visitors.

Comment: Why can't we use a local copy of jquery?

Comment: Slightly late, but you could use [decentraleyes](https://decentraleyes.org/). It's available for Firefox, Chrome, and Opera, and loads some scripts that usually rely on CDN's (like jquery) from a local repo instead. I use it to speed up sites, but I'd imagine you could use it to avoid having sites blocked for common scripts in CDN's that for some reason aren't available (temporary/permanent outage, blocked on the network, etc). It won't help for general SE scripts (as they're site-specific and aren't included), but it'll at least help avoiding jquery issues. SE works without JS too btw.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a practical solution for users: Fortunately there's this addon called [LocalCDN](https://www.localcdn.org/) that works exactly as its name suggests: It blocks those requests to CDNs and loads up those resources locally, hence this makes loading up jQuery possible even when `ajax.googleapis.com` is blocked or unreachable.

[image]

Not only is this better for unbreaking StackExchange on those networks, but also for speed (especially on that poor 4G network that my mobile phone uses with that [addon installed on Firefox Nightly](https://codeberg.org/nobody/LocalCDN/wiki#user-content-13-can-i-use-localcdn-in-firefox-for-android-fenix), bonus I get to save some Mbs of bandwidth as well and I cannot stress how much my mobile 4G browsing experience has improved since I adopted that addon) but it also protects your privacy from those spooky "free" CDNs.

The addon is free and completely open source (there's even an [auditing script](https://codeberg.org/nobody/LocalCDN/src/branch/main/audit) to verify the integrity of the bundled resources) and I would encourage everyone to give it a try. Anyway hope at least someone will find this useful.