# Why doesn't Stackoverflow use a jquery fallback

Tags: discussion, jquery, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a fallback for jQuery in case it fails to load from Google's CDN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133786/add-a-fallback-for-jquery-in-case-it-fails-to-load-from-googles-cdn)

In the case of Google's CDN for jquery going down (which happens every so often) SO becomes unusable. What is the reason for not using a fallback such as the one from boilerplate?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: Great question. Seems like it should (no rep to upvote)

Comment: (I know that's a request, and this is a discussion, but Waffles (then a Stack Exchange developer) did reply with his thoughts, so it's pretty close.)