# Give debug info in F12 Developer Console

Tags: feature-request

#### Background story

I'm in China where *all of Google* is blocked, including the Google Ajax library.

I use [Resource Override](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii) (not affiliated!) to override this URL to a local copy of that script, so all Stack Exchange sites worked well for a while.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
```

Some time ago, however, the red banner showed up again. It took me a quarter to realize that there's another version of jQuery loaded from Google:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
```

So I overrode it again.

#### Proposal

It would have taken only a few seconds if the failed script was told to me. I propose that whatever failure in loading pages, sending Ajax calls, etc., be displayed in the F12 Developer Console. This will be very helpful.

***Why?***

First, it saves time an interested person needs to find out what's going wrong.

Second, the majority of Stack Exchange visitors go to Stack Overflow, the majority of which are developers who know and are interested in debugging, especially in this very case where Stack sites only malfunction in known ways. I wouldn't propose the same to Google, because their users are not primarily developers.

Comment: related: [Load jQuery from Stack's CDN if Google's CDN is blocked (or replace it alltogether)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133786/134300)

Comment: What is the "F12 Developer Console"? Specific to Firefox?

Comment: @PeterMortensen no, it exists in all modern browsers I know of. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already possible on the Developer Console itself (at least tested on Chrome).

In addition to the beloved "Console", there's also a "Network" tab that displays most (if not all) the requests and their HTTP status (even for AJAX calls).

> [image: Network tab on Chrome's Developer Console]

Answer (score 0):

It would be an option that SE hosts the file themselves. If they don't want to leave the (often already loaded) Google CDN files, there are options to load the file from their own server if the Google CDN attempt fails. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18677056/993547) SO post for example.)

If you want diagnostic information in your developer console, I'm sorry, that is not really the job of SE. If you choose to alter the code and replace it with the wrong one, no diagnostics are going to help.