# What's the plural of "animuson"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

If the plural of "moose" is "moosen," what's the plural of "animuson"?

Skimming MSE questions on the Android app tonight revealed [one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259733/266359) that was closed by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)...twice:

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happened because animuson voted to close before [being hired as Stack Exchange employee](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/) (giving him moderator privileges all over the network), then later closed with the diamond.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Actually I cheated and recorded two votes so both duplicates would show up. :P

Comment: so you cann't just add one more duplicate post :D i feel sorry for you ( you have to work really hard ) LOL

Comment: @animuson Cheater!!