Have an option to permanently switch to the jQuery fallback across all SE sites
Every SE site loads script from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js. Unfortunately, the majority of Google's domains, including ajax.googleapis.com, are blocked by GFW.
Here is the loading speed of https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js in China (>10s includes timeout):

This causes in Chinese mainland users to experience a significant delay of up to 50s or more before they can view the banner:

... requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load. [Retry using another source].

Then click to switch to the fallback /Content/Js/third-party/jquery-1.12.4.min.js.
Such delays always occur during:

First time visiting the site
1 month after switching to fallback (due to expiration of cookies)

Personally, I think it would be convenient if there was an option to permanently switch to the fallback across all SE sites.

related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331951/technical-reasons-to-use-googleapis-com-on-se-websites

related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259733/using-google-cdn-to-load-scripts-gives-poor-user-experience-in-china

I'd rather see websites go away from these "convenient/fashionable" (for the developer) services, be it fonts, libraries or anything else, they're only good for extra visitor tracking. I actually cache requests for these sites myself locally: com.googleapis.ajax has 41 versions of jQuery, com.cloudflare.cdnjs has 21. And while font files are cached, those fonts.googleapis.com/css requests are practically all unique, there are thousands different ones.
Being self-contained is good, being fragmented and unnecessarily tracking the user is not. IMHO.

@biziclop goes codidact.com: What do you use to cache requests?

@This_is_NOT_a_forum: I use a self-grown PHP script under Apache.
