# Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load

Tags: discussion, javascript, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message)

I just can't use StackOverFlow website due to this JS issue. What is wrong?

Edit:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

The file is this, and I'm encountering it in every browser (Chrome, Safari, FF).

Edit 2 (can't add comments due to js issue...) a 404 not found.

Comment: And which domain is that? In which browser did you encounter this? On which page does it happen, and does it happen always?

Comment: Also, how are you using it *now*?

Comment: When you click the link in your question, what is the error message you are receiving?