# message about JavaScript being blocked

Tags: support, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message)

On Stack Overflow, and all of the Stack Exchange sites, there is big message at the top of all pages saying "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load." I have JavaScript enabled and I didn't make any changes recently. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I'm using FireFox 14 on Windows 7.

Also the tags in  this question are failing to load. I get messages about "are you human?" and I have to fill in a captcha.

Comment: For the record, I am not seeing this (from London, England)

Comment: Check whether one of the addons are disabling Javascript, or someone disable Javascript on Firefox. I don't have any problem with it.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of some sort? (Mobile/Enterprise system?)

Comment: Enterprise proxy

Comment: Does it claim to optimise/protect you perchance?

Comment: Not sure but it looks like the traffic is coming from a different country than I am in.