# What am I supposed to do when I get what is probably the "requires external JavaScript" error for the chat domains and SEDE?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, data-explorer, jquery

I'm suddenly getting [this error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89433/997587) in my main sites (like SO and MSE)

> Meta Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load. Retry using another source.

I did find out what's causing it on the surface level (not on a deeper level), which I posted about [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392109/997587), but that's not what this question is about. My question here is what I'm supposed to do when it looks like I'm hitting a related thing for the chat domains. When I try to open a chatroom now, the page gets stuck showing "*Loading {chatroom name}<br>Just a second…*", and in the browser console, I see "*Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined*".

I also get something similar for SEDE. Running a query takes me to `data.stackexchange.com/query/save/1` and I get a "*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $ is not a function*" in the browser console.

I know how I can work around my *particular case* of the issue, but I don't like those solutions because they would negatively affect the rest of my browsing experience for sites other than Stack Exchange sites.

So what can I do? I suppose this is partially a feature-request asking for a similar "*Retry using another source.*" button for the chat domains and SEDE.